# How to check if two char values in Array are the same?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a given char array and have to remove the duplicate letters in it. How can I do this in Java?

**Example:**

Given char array:

```
char[] s = { 'H','e','l','l','o','W','o','r','l','d','!'};
```

Expected result:

```
char[] s = { 'H','e','l','o','W','r','d','!'};
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I only wrote for(int i=0; i<s.length. i++){
}
and don't know how to continue

Comment: Can you use collections?

Comment: I am not allowed to and don't know how they work anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove duplicates like this and get a new char array,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] array = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!'};
        String temp = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (temp.indexOf(array[i]) == -1)
                temp = temp + array[i];
        }
        char[] reslut = temp.toCharArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is correct. I believe the asker would learn more from more explanation and less code.